# Dynamic property type with Gson

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I am using Retrofit to request API but I have a problem with the response.When the property is empty it returns `[]`, else it returns `Map<String, MyObject>`. How can it parse the response to `Object` in both cases?

Comment: That depends on how you are modelling the response

Comment: @Chisko Please explain. In the JSON response, it returns [] means this is JsonArray, and it returns Map means this is JsonObject.

Comment: Note that i can not change the response from server

Answer (score 1):

A quick type adapter can take care of that. For example,

```
class EmptyArrayAdapter<T> implements JsonDeserializer<T> {

  @Override
  public T deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext jsc) throws JsonParseException {

    if (json.isJsonArray()) {
      // It is an array instead of a Map, 
      // Return an empty object (could also just return null)
      return jsc.deserialize(new JsonObject(), typeOfT);
    } else {
      return jsc.deserialize(json, typeOfT);
    }
  }
}
```

Note since this adapter uses `jsc.deserialize` with the same type it is passed, you have to use it via the `@JsonAdapter` annotation on a field --

```
class MyObject {
  @JsonAdapter(EmptyArrayAdapter.class)
  Map<String, SomeObj> myField;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. You saved my day.